# Why do I receive these errors when I use pytube?

Tags: python, pytube

My problem: When using the pytube package in the official Python IDLE, I receive a long list of errors. I am just playing around with a python YouTube video downloader and I'm not quite sure what is going on. I have a current python script that when ran, gives me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\owenr\Desktop\Python Video Downloader.py", line 6, in <module>
    yt = YouTube(link)
  File "C:\Users\owenr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 104, in __init__
    self.prefetch()
  File "C:\Users\owenr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 221, in prefetch
    self.vid_info_raw = request.get(self.vid_info_url)
  File "C:\Users\owenr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytube\request.py", line 42, in get
    return _execute_request(url, headers=extra_headers).read().decode("utf-8")
  File "C:\Users\owenr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytube\request.py", line 26, in _execute_request
    return urlopen(request)  # nosec
  File "C:\Users\owenr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\owenr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 523, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\owenr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 632, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Users\owenr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 555, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\owenr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\owenr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 747, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\owenr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 523, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\owenr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 632, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Users\owenr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 561, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\owenr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\owenr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

The original code is,

```
from pytube import YouTube
import time
import sys
while True:
    link = input("Enter the link:")
    yt = YouTube(link)

    print("Information:")
    time.sleep(1.25)

    print("    Title: ", yt.title)
    print("    Number of views: ", yt.views)
    print("    Length of video: ", yt.views)
    print("    Ratings: ", yt.rating)
    time.sleep(1)
    
    yn = input("Is this correct? [Y / n]")
    if yn == "Y":
        print("Downloading...")
        stream = yt.streams.first()
        stream.download('C:\\Users\\owenr\\Desktop\\Python Videos')
        sys.exit("Status: Completed")
    if yn == "n":
        time.sleep(1)
        continue
```

I receive very similar errors when I run this in the IDLE, not from the '.py' file (As shown above).

```
>>> from pytube import YouTube
>>> yt = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TWJaFD6R2s')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    yt = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TWJaFD6R2s')
  File "C:\Users\owenr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 104, in __init__
    self.prefetch()
  File "C:\Users\owenr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 221, in prefetch
    self.vid_info_raw = request.get(self.vid_info_url)
  File "C:\Users\owenr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytube\request.py", line 42, in get
    return _execute_request(url, headers=extra_headers).read().decode("utf-8")
  File "C:\Users\owenr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytube\request.py", line 26, in _execute_request
    return urlopen(request)  # nosec
  File "C:\Users\owenr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\owenr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 523, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\owenr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 632, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Users\owenr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 555, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\owenr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\owenr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 747, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\owenr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 523, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\owenr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 632, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Users\owenr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 561, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\owenr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\owenr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

The link used in this example is entirely arbitrary. As you can see, the errors only show after

```
yt = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TWJaFD6R2s')
```

If somebody could help me figure out what is going on here and how to fix it, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: That link doesn't exist.  What do you want to happen in that case?

Comment: With all due respect, are you sure? I have checked and checked again and each time it comes to '#Stereo: Left and Right Stereo Sound Test' found on YouTube.

Comment: No, I'm not sure; I was just assuming based on the 404 Not Found error.

Comment: This is not an IDLE issue.  You would get the same error if you run in the standard Python console (without involving IDLE) before upgrading pytube).  One should best do this with any code behavior problem to determine if IDLE is involved or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a problem with the PyTube library. There is an issue about it here: https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/495

It looks like it has been recently fixed (as of 9 hours ago) and a new release was issued 27 minutes ago.

I'd suggest upgrading by calling `pip install pytube --upgrade` and trying your code again.